# Error handling requests using RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I'm having two observables the first checks whether the AccessToken exist and if not return `NotLoggedIn` error type. The second fetches user data and should be called if the AccessToken in `rx_validate` exist. However I can't seem to figure out how I combine these observables to also error handle `rx_fetchUserData` errors from the response.

**Error Enum**

```
enum LoginError: Error {
    case NotLoggedIn
    case Unknown
    case NoConnection
}
```

**observables in viewModel**

```
// MARK: validate if user is logged in
public func rx_validate() -> Observable<String> {
    return Observable.create({ observer in

        //Check if AccessToken exist
        if let token = AccessToken.current {
            observer.onNext(token.authenticationToken)
            observer.onCompleted()
        } else {
            observer.onError(LoginError.NotLoggedIn)
        }

        return Disposables.create()
    })
}

// MARK: Fetch data
public func rx_fetchUserData(token: String) -> Observable<User> {
    return Network.provider
        .request(.auth(fbToken:  token))
        .retry(1).debug()
        .mapObject(User.self)

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use `flatMap`:

```
rx_validate()
.flatMap { token in
    return rx_fetchUserData(token: token)
}
.subscribe(onNext: { user in
    // do something with the user  
},
onError: { error in
    // manage errors        
})
```